# How can I use LIMIT 1 in subquery

Tags: sql, vertica

I'm trying to run an update querywith a table that joins on itself and I want to assign the column `M_USER` to the first row that the select statement is returning. I know in SQL Server, I could use `TOP 1` and i think the equivalent would be `LIMIT 1` in Vertica.

So I tried to write the query with the `LIMIT 1` but i'm getting this error:

`ERROR: Correlated subquery expression without aggregates and with limit is not supported`

Here's my query:

```
UPDATE REPORT.sub_2019 a
SET M_USER= (Select u.UPDATED_USER 
        from REPORT.sub_2019 u 
        where u.MBR_ID = a.MBR_ID 
        and u.NAME= a.NAME and u.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending' limit 1)
where a.RESULT is not null
```

I just want to grab the first `UPDATED_USER` that the subquery is returning. Should I use LIMIT or any other way of writing the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the rank function for this:

```
UPDATE REPORT.sub_2019 a
SET M_USER= (Select u.UPDATED_USER, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY <field> ORDER BY <field> DESC) as rank 
        from REPORT.sub_2019 u 
        where u.MBR_ID = a.MBR_ID 
        and u.NAME= a.NAME 
        and u.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending'
        and rank = 1)
where a.RESULT is not null
```

Comment: This won't work because you're using rank in the where clause of the same statement that you referencing it. I tried adding another `SELECT UPDATED_USER FROM` on top and putting the rank outside the statement but i'm getting the error `Correlated expression in set operator subquery is not supported`

Answer (score 0):

Use max or min in subquery

```
UPDATE REPORT.sub_2019 a
SET M_USER= (Select min(u.UPDATED_USER )
        from REPORT.sub_2019 u 
        where u.MBR_ID = a.MBR_ID 
        and u.NAME= a.NAME and u.STATUS_REASON = 'Pending')
where a.RESULT is not null
```